# Use Select method to traverse an IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#, collections

I have the following method that I use to traverse collections like IQueryCollection, IHeadersDictionary and IFormCollection

```
public static string ToString(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> dic)
{
    string res = "";
    foreach (var item in dic)
    {
        res += item.Key + "=" + item.Value + "&";
    }
    return res.TrimEnd('&');
}
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to do it in a more " functional" style, using something like *Select* and *String.Join* method

I'm using dot-net-core 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can write it using a select, it's actually quite simple:

```
public static string ToString(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> dic)
{
    return string.Join("&", dic.Select(_ => $"{_.Key}={_.Value}"));
}
```

Will it perform better, hard to say without testing, your version uses string concatenations which are probably not a good idea for a large number of string (`StringBuilder`) would be better. But I expect `string.Join` to do a better job than your version.

Comment: This is one of the first things I tried, because of examples I saw on the web, but got the following error: error CS1061: 'IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)... I guess I must be missing something...

Comment: Are you sure you have a `using System.Linq;` in your file ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- Using `Aggregate`

  ```
  dic.Aggregate((res, item) => res + item.Key + "=" + item.Value + "&")
     .TrimEnd('&')
  ```
- Using `Select` and `string.Join`

  ```
  string.Join("&", dic.Select(item => item.Key + "=" + item.Value))
  ```
- Using `Zip` and `string.Join` if you are using a `Dictionary` instance instead of a list of `KeyValuePairs`:

  ```
  string.Join("&", dict.Keys.Zip(dict.Values, (key, value) => key + "=" + value))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var result = from keyvaluepair in dictionary
        from value in keyvaluepair .Value
        select keyvaluepair .Key + "=" + value;
```

or try aggregate,

```
string result = values.Aggregate("",
              (key, pair) =>
                key + "=" + pair.Key + ":"
                  + pair.Value.Aggregate("",
                      (str, val) => str + "=" + val)
              );
```

There is already a post related to same in [How do I combine the keys and values of a Dictionary into one List using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753321/how-do-i-combine-the-keys-and-values-of-a-dictionary-into-one-list-using-linq)